# How to find the hidden link of mp3 files on the website | Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

How to find the hidden link of mp3 files by Python on **radiojavan.com** website

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6qSD.png)

For example, on `radiojavan.com`, you only see the page link, but there is no download link. What tools can I use to find the music link in `Python`?
please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

simply like this :

```
import re
def exp(url):
    try:
        url = url.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
        op = requests.get(url , timeout=7).content
        if ".mp3" in op:
            print ("thanks it's valid link ")
            filter = re.findall('<meta property="og:audio" content="(.*?)"/>', str(op))[0]
            print ("[+] Found " + filter)
        else:
            print ('-> ' + url)
    except:
        print ("timeOut -> " + url)
        pass


a = raw_input("link : ")
exp(a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.radiojavan.com/mp3s/mp3/Hojat-Ashrafzadeh-Kaman-Abroo'
# download page source
r = requests.get(url)
# convert to text
page_source = r.text

# look through each line for '.mp3'
for line in page_source.split("\n"):
    if ".mp3" in line:
        # select the text after 'content="' and before the following '"'
        mp3url = line.strip().split('content="')[1].split('"')[0]
        print (mp3url)
```